# Changed user account name, but the old one is still valid

Tags: windows-xp, user-accounts

On Windows XP, I changed my user account name but still the old user is working. I even changed the computer name and ID to my name, but everywhere I can see the old user name.

When I log in and write my new user, it works fine.

I even restarted my PC.

Comment: Did you change the name of your current user or did you create a new user account? If you created a new account, you must deactivate the old account.

Comment: Your question really is not clear. Can you show us some screenshots maybe, as an example?

Comment: Raystafarian, i change name of my current user i didn't create a new user account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only changed the „display name” of the account, not the real login name.

Comment: how i can change the real login name?

Comment: @khalid You don’t.

Answer (score 1):

Renaming a user only changes the "label" of the user. In the background each user has a SID (security identifier) which is constant.

> Because it retains its security identifier (SID), a renamed user
>   account retains all its other properties, such as its description,
>   password, group memberships, user environment profile, account
>   information, and any assigned permissions and rights.

From http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/lsm_rename_user.mspx

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the user profile name remains the old one, that is expected.  So if old user was User1 and you changed it to User2, the account name will change and you log on as User2.  However, the profile in documents and settings will remain User1.  User1 will still appear in other places but the account User1 does not really exist

Comment: i dont want user1 to be appear again. is it possiable?